# Material Checkboxes not working with their 'checked' derivative

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a table of records where the first cell in each column has a checkbox.  when the checkbox is clicked, I store that record's id into an array in typescript:

```
onCheckboxClick(id) {
  if (this.selectedInvoiceables.indexOf(id) > -1) {
    this.selectedInvoiceables.splice(id, 1);
  } else {
    this.selectedInvoiceables.push(id);
  }
  if (this.selectedInvoiceables.length > 1) {
    this.disableBulkEdit = false;
  } else {
    this.disableBulkEdit = true;
  }
}
```

and here is the checkbox:

```
<mat-checkbox
   class="checkbox"
   (change)="onCheckboxClick(invoice.id)"
   id = "invoiceCheckbox{{invoice.id}}"
   [checked]="selectedInvoiceables.indexOf(invoice.id) > -1"
> </mat-checkbox>
```

So, whenever the checkboxes are clicked, we store the id.  And that works fine, however, there seems to be an issue where clicking on one checkbox will deselect another checkbox even though the value is still contained in my `selectedInvoiceables` array.  Is my current check for the `[checked]` derivative not good enough or being refreshed irregularly?

Comment: When calling `.splice()`, the first parameter should be the index of the array element, not the element itself. Pass the result of `.indexOf()`.

Comment: @DarthJDG thank you, ill give that shot

Comment: That worked thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the `[(ngModel)]=""` syntax to bind the model/state of the checkbox to values:

- https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/examples

Comment: Are you suggesting to use `[(ngModel)]="selectedInvoiceables.indexOf(invoice.id) > -1"` ?

Comment: i used the solution from Darth in the comments, but this also satisfied my needs, so I am approving it for a correct answer.